# Is it possible to use parentheses with \citeA and square brackets with \cite in apacite?

Tags: citing, apacite

Usually citations use parentheses or square brackets in all cases. SBC (Brazilian Computer Society) has an odd case. Its style for references use parentheses everywhere, except when making *parenthetical* citations. In the case of *parenthetical* citations, one must use square brackets: [AuthorX 1999].

As an minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = 1986,
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section{Demonstration} 

To adhere to SBC (Brazilian Computer Society) style:

This citation should be using square brackets:~\cite{Knu86}.

This should be using parentheses:~\citeA{Knu86}.

And this citation should be using square brackets:~\cite{Knu86}.

References should also be using parentheses!

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

How can I change only the \cite behavior of apacite to use square brackets, while maintaining all other apacite commands to still use parentheses?

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Add a MWE, please.

Comment: Added a MWE, as requested.

Comment: Are you sure you want ([Author 1999]) and not (Author [1999])? I.e, should the brackets be around the whole author+year or just around the year?

Comment: It's only [AuthorX 1999].

Comment: So no parentheses at all, just square brackets *instead* of parentheses?

Comment: Yep. In this case its to use only square brackets and none parentheses. All other cases must be in parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the internal `\@cite` command so that it changes the brackets in just those cases.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = 1986,
    title = {The {\TeX{ book},
  }}}
\end{filecontents}
%
\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@cite}{\def\@BBOP{[}\def\@BBCP{]}}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Demonstration} 

To adhere to SBC (Brazilian Computer Society) style:

This citation should be using square brackets:~\cite{Knu86}.

This should be using parentheses:~\citeA{Knu86}.

And this citation should be using square brackets:~\cite{Knu86}.

References should also be using parentheses!

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @EdsonCésar I've updated the answer with a version that requires a lot less code. Since the addition is quite simple, it's nicer to use the `etoolbox` patching facilities to add the code. Then you don't need to copy the whole command.